# htaccess rewrite rule for query not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im having problems with the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^submit\?t=([^/]*)$ /index.php?escribir=$1 [L]
```

I want to redirect from `/submit?t=word` to `index.php?escribir=word` but its not working.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match a query string using a `RewriteRule` directive. That is documented. You need to match and capture it using a `RewriteCond` instead. Reason ist that the rule only matches against the path part of the URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?submit/?$ /index.php?escribir=%1 [QSD,END]
```

The more general approach that allows for other query arguments being specified and preserves those:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)t=([^&]*)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?submit/?$ /index.php?escribir=%1 [QSA,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Very well explained answer!